# Echoing Complex Array in Structured Manner

Tags: php

```
$hours = [
  'Mon' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Tue' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Wed' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Thu' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Fri' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Sat' => ['10:00 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Sun' => ['closed']
];
```

I'm having trouble echoing out the above array to be structured as:

Mon - 7:30 am - 4:00 pm

Tue - 7:30 am - 4:00 pm

...

in some type of structured way either in a table or within divs that I could structure using CSS.

Comment: What trouble are you having? Please show what you've tried so we can help you learn from your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you, it echos the array in a table

```
$hours = [
  'Mon' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Tue' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Wed' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Thu' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Fri' => ['07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Sat' => ['10:00 AM' => '04:00 PM'],
  'Sun' => ['closed']
];


echo "<table>";
foreach($hours as $key => $value)
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
   foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
   {
       echo "<td>" . (($key2!=0)?$key2:'') . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $value2 . "</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<?php 
$hours = array(
'Mon' => array('07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'),
'Tue' => array('07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'),
'Wed' => array('07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'),
'Thu' => array('07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'),
'Fri' => array('07:30 AM' => '04:00 PM'),
'Sat' => array('10:00 AM' => '04:00 PM'),
'Sun' => array('closed')
); 


foreach ($hours as $key=>$val){
    $html='';
    $html.= $key."   ";
    if(is_array($val)){
        foreach($val as $key1=>$val1){
            if($key1 == 0){
                $html.= $val1.'<br>';
            }else{
            $html.= $key1."   ".$val1.'<br>';

        }
    }}else{
        $html.= $val.'<br>';
    }
    echo $html;
}

?>
```

array structure i have changed for my own you can change it.